# Php getting data from Android device opening URL from QR

Tags: php, android, qr-code

I would like to ask for something that I don´t know if it is even posible.

Lets suppose I have a QR-code that, after reading, send to ascertain URL in my server with PHP. Is it possible to get any data from the device? The situation is, i want to deploy QR codes, that when reaching my server, can offer random prizes to the device user (or save it...) But I need some data, IMEI, phone number, so I know who are the winners.

Has someone ever had a similar need?

I have searched this whole site, but cant find any answer.

Comment: Honestly, if this is possible I'm throwing my phone away.

Comment: qr codes are just data. generally they're a URL or something, but that's just for convenience. if you want a qr code containing the phone's imei, then you have to get that phone imei and encode it into url you embed in the qr code. you're NOT going to get imei from anything the webview/browser handling the url on the phone sends to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this would be possible would be to write your own QR code scanner app & have the user install it. And even then, I'm not sure that this wouldn't violate some sort of security control on the device.

The reason for this is simple: the QR code simply encodes a static string like a URL. There is no provision in the QR code itself to insert additional data to the URL after the device reads it - this would have to be done by an application on the user's device. And while I haven't researched all the various QR code reading apps out there, I would be surprised if the most common ones did anything like this.

What you might do is play around with a QR code scanner: set up a web server with PHP, create a QR code that points to it, and examine the request that your server gets when the code is scanned. My guess is that you'll just find the standard HTTP headers, but you might find information in there that you can use.

But the best solution to this kind of functionality would be to have the QR code point to a web page with a form on it where the user can enter their email address. This has the added benefit that you can then collect customer email addresses (with full disclosure of what you're doing with that information, of course).

Comment: "But the best solution to this kind of functionality would be to have the QR code point to a web page with a form on it where the user can enter their email address. This has the added benefit that you can then collect customer email addresses (with full disclosure of what you're doing with that information, of course)." - Thank you Kryte, actually what i suposed. But i wanted to give a faster reward, well, just in case someone here, more expert than me, knew some magic solution. :)